# What is the optimal way to store port numbers in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, int

If I want to store a port number in MySQL, what is the most efficient way (minimizing wasted space) to do so?  Is it `INT(5)` or `INT(3)`?

I'm looking [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) and I think the answer is `INT(3)` (or perhaps `MEDIUMINT`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Port number is an unsinged 16-bit integer. That means the highest value can be 65535.
So you can use SMALLINT.

Comment: Yes it has to be UNSIGNED SMALLINT. The storage size would be the same but you would have only a range from -32768 to 32767...

Answer (score 7):

If you want to store the values as compactly as possible, the choice would be `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` which takes 2 bytes of storage.

See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) for details.

Also FYI `INT(5)` and `INT(3)` both use 4 bytes of storage. The `(5)` and `(3)` are only used for display, not for storage.